# Going through Python the Hard Way and trying to improvise code

Tags: python, function

I'm on exercise 21 of Learn Python the Hard Way.

Here is the original code:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)


# A puzzle for the extra credit, type it in anyway.
print "Here is a puzzle."

what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

Now I am trying to make the code my own by creating a new function and return.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def number_of_food(restaurants, grocery):
    print "ADDING food places %r + %r" % (restaurants, grocery)
    return restaurants + grocery

number_restaurants = int(raw_input("How many restaurants are there?"))
number_grocery = int(raw_input("How many grocery stores are there?"))
number_of_food = (number_restaurants, number_grocery)
```

I get absolutely no errors. It asks how many restaurants there are and how many grocery stores but then it ends. Am I missing something? I am basically trying to take the values I get from the `raw_input` and `print` them in the function. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You are not calling the function `number_of_food`

Answer (score 1):

`number_of_food = (number_restaurants, number_grocery)`
With the line above, you are **not** calling the function you just defined. Instead; you are overwriting it with a tuple. First, you need to remove the assignment operator(`=`).
Even if you removed it; it will not print the value returned by your function. You have to add `print` keyword too.

```
def number_of_food(restaurants, grocery):
    print "ADDING food places %r + %r" % (restaurants, grocery)
    return restaurants + grocery

number_restaurants = int(raw_input("How many restaurants are there?"))
number_grocery = int(raw_input("How many grocery stores are there?"))
total_places = number_of_food(number_restaurants, number_grocery) 
# Just remove the '=', so it will call the function
print "There are %r places for food."%total_places 
#This will print the returned value
```

Comment: Oh perfect! I guess I just thought the assignment operator was necessary but it was in fact ruining it. That makes so much more sense! Thank you.